# Convert Active Record Object into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model Person with fields email, name, age, phone_number. I want to convert `Person.all` to a hash.
The hash should have the structure as follows:

```
{
"email1" => ["name", "age", "phone_number"],
"email2" => ["name2", "age2", "phone_number2"]
....
}
```

I tried `as_json`, `map` or `attributes` etc. But it returns array of hashes. How can I create this custom structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it from below query,

```
Hash[Person.all.collect { |user| [user.email, user.attributes.except(:email).values] }]
```

If you want to omit other attributes like `created_at` & `updated_at`, run

```
Hash[Person.all.collect { |user| [user.email, user.attributes.except(:email, :created_at, :updated_at).values] }]
```

Comment: In recent rubies you can use `Hash#to_h` instead of `Hash#[]` which is somewhat more semantic, `[[:a, 3]].to_h # -> {:a=>3} `